# Regex Pattern for ignoring a custom escape character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find a suitable regex for matching pair of custom characters in an input string. These custom characters are replaced by their corresponding html tags.

For e.g.
The input string  can have underscores in pairs to indicate words in bold. Hence,
`_Name_` outputs as `<b>Name</b>`

However if there is a genuine underscore in the string, it cannot be replaced by "bold" tags and has to be ignored. The genuine underscore has to be preceded by `/` (I couldn't find a better character, it could be one more underscore or hyphen or whatever). 
Any single or paired occurrance of this genuine underscore has to be ignored by regex.

So far I could come up with this regex:

```
var pattern = @"(?!/)_(.*?)(?!/)_";
```

But it fails in below input string:

`_Tom_Katy/_Richard/_/_Stephan_and many users`

It outputs as

```
<b>Tom</b>Katy/<b>Richard/_/</b>Stephan_and many users
```

Many Thanks in Advance,
Pr

Comment: Your first (?!/) should be a lookbehind, not a lokahead

Comment: @Gabber: The second one should be a lookbehind, too.

Comment: Doesn't the lookbehind seek before the whole regex?

Comment: question is incomplete..you should specify what are the `valid` outputs and `invalid` outputs..this would help others to understand ur question!

Comment: @AlanMoore understand now, edited my answer thanks to your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@"(?<!/)_([^/]+?)[^/]_"
```

This finds any character sequence without `/` inside it, if you want to include `/` in your search try this way

```
@"(?<!\/)_(.+?)((?<!\/)_)"
```

Explanation:

```
(?<!/)      # this is a negative lookbehind, it says "I don't want the previous char to be /
_           # finds the first _
([^/]+?)   # tells to search characters without / (in this case your names)
[^/]_"      # finds the last _ not preceded by / (maybe redundant seen the previous one)
```

Comment: The `(.*?)` doesn't come into play until after the leading underscore is consumed, so that's not the problem.  But switching to `(.+?)` is probably a good idea anyway; otherwise `__` (two consecutive underscores) will be converted to `<b></b>`.

Comment: Thanks a Million.. Tried both and works perfectly..I still am not able to get the logic behind this regex. Any links to help? What does the character "<" do here?

Comment: Well, Thanks a lot again Gabber, :)